# Tracked files are deleted when running "git clean -xdf" in yarn workspaces

Tags: git, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

When running `git clean -xdf` in a repo with yarn workspaces, the contents of the workspaces are deleted.

Consider this folder structure:

- workspace1

  - **index.js**
  - **package.json**
- workspace2

  - **index.js**
  - **package.json**
- .gitignore
- README.md
- package.json
- yarn.lock

After running `git clean -xfd` the files in bold (tracked source controlled files) are deleted! Even though clean shouldn't have impacted tracked files at all.

I believe it is a yarn workspaces bug. I've opened an issue @yarn:
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7536

Has anyone encountered this bug? Does anyone have a workaround or know the root cause for this behavior?

For anyone interested in seeing the bug first hand I've created a repo that causes it to reproduce easily:
https://github.com/Shmulik-Kravitz/yarn-with-git-bug

Steps to reproduce are inside.

Output for `yarn --verbose` (very long):
https://github.com/Shmulik-Kravitz/yarn-with-git-bug/blob/master/yarn%20log

Output for `git clean -xdf`:

```
Removing node_modules/
```

Output for `git status`:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    workspace1/index.js
        deleted:    workspace1/package.json
        deleted:    workspace2/index.js
        deleted:    workspace2/package.json

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Can you add the files to .gitignore?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you think the bug is. What files are getting deleted, and why did you expect them not to be? Were they tracked, clean, ...? How does the `private` attribute message relate to the rest?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: This actually reproduces! I have no idea why...
I did Clone, yarn (in root),  git clean -xdf and these files got removed by git-clean

Comment: Please describe the exact steps to reproduce the bug in the question itself, instead of linking to an external site. Also: (1) What is the output if you run yarn with `--verbose`? (2) What is the output of `git status` before and after running yarn?

Comment: `git clean` says what it's deleting.  Those files are gone, but `git clean` didn't delete them.  Also, when I try this, nothing deletes them, they're still there.  You've got some since-fixed bug (and I'd bet it's in yarn, deleting tracked files would be an _extremely_ high priority Git bug) or there's some way to misconfigure yarn.  Do the yarn run then check whether the files are there.

Comment: After running ```yarn``` the files do exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Windows, I bet the most probable reason is the following issue: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/607 . Git was indeed deleting the content of junction points.

I could reproduce your issue with "git version 2.22.0.windows.1", but no longer see it after upgrading to "git version 2.23.0.windows.1".

Comment: Yah, Windows's implementation of "symlinks" is badly broken, there's a reason Unix filesystems don't allow hard cross-tree directory links but that's apparently the only kind Windows knows.